# doble filtrado con pandas no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Debo filtrar dos veces un dataframe con datos de educacion y salario de un conjunto de personas. Primero debo saber que educacion tienen:

```
# with and without `Bachelors`, `Masters`, or `Doctorate`
higher_education = df[df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")].count()
lower_education = df[~df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")].count()
```

Para luego filtrar nuevamente (considerando ya el filtrado anterior) para obtener unicamente el porcentaje de personas que ganan mas de 50k.

```
# percentage with salary >50K
higher_education_rich = df[df[higher_education, (df["salary"] == ">50K")].count() / higher_education] * 100
print("THIS IS THE PERCENTAGE THAT MATTERS: ", higher_education_rich["salary"])
    # imprime un boolean
  # los indexes no son los mismos, lo previene la variable "higher_education". Como usarla sin limitarme el uso luego de "salary"?
lower_education_rich = df[df[lower_education, (df["salary"] == ">50K")].count() / lower_education] * 100
print(lower_education_rich["salary"])
```

Este codigo me devuelve booleans, pero no puedo ver cual es el error (ya sea por una mala logica o por mala sintaxis).

Edit: Dejo en este [link](https://replit.com/@MatiasRico/boilerplate-demographic-data-analyzer#adult.data.csv) un ejemplo de los datos que debo filtrar. El archivo (.csv) puede ser descargado para mas facilidad.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos sobre los que operan tus expresiones para poder hacer pruebas y averiguar qué sucede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un pequeño lío en un par de lugares.

Primero, en esta expresión:

```
df[df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")].count()
```

La primera parte de la expresión (sin el `.count()`) te selecciona dentro del dataframe `df` sólo las filas que corresponden a las personas con educación superior. El resultado es otro dataframe (con las mismas columnas que el original pero con menos filas). Al aplicar `count()` sobre él, te cuenta **para cada columna** cuántos elementos tiene esa columna.

El resultado de aplicar `.count()` es esto:

```html
age               7491
workclass         7491
fnlwgt            7491
education         7491
education-num     7491
marital-status    7491
occupation        7491
relationship      7491
race              7491
sex               7491
capital-gain      7491
capital-loss      7491
hours-per-week    7491
native-country    7491
salary            7491
```

Esto no tiene mucho sentido calcularlo. Todas las columnas tienen el mismo número de elementos (7491) y no queremos ese resultado repetido para cada columna. Si lo que queremos es simplemente contar cuántas personas tienen estudios superiores, basta mirar cuántas filas tiene el dataframe resultante tras el filtrado. El número de filas te lo da `len(dataframe)`

Así que quitamos el `.count()` para quedarnos con el dataframe filtrado (pues lo vamos a usar más adelante) y usamos `len()` para contar cuántos elementos tiene cada uno de esos dataframes y guardamos ese número en variables separadas.

```
higher_education = df[df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")]
lower_education = df[~df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")]

num_higher_education = len(higher_education)
num_lower_education = len(lower_education)
```

Después, a la hora de calcular el porcentaje de ricos tienes esto:

```
higher_education_rich = df[df[higher_education, (df["salary"] == ">50K")].count() / higher_education] * 100
```

Lo cual estaba mal por varias razones. Dentro de los primeros corchetes tienes una expresión así:

```
df[higher_education, (...mas cosas aqui...)]
```

Esto está usando lo que contenga la variable `higher_education` como selector de filas dentro de `df`. Eso está mal, pues para que funcionara la variable `higher_education` debería contener una lista de booleanos tan larga como `df` para seleccionar aquellas filas en las que hubiera `True`.

En cambio `higher_education` contiene como antes vimos el número 7491 repetido unas cuantas veces. Pero es que aunque eso hubiera funcionado, para seleccionar las filas correctas, después tenías entre paréntesis otra expresión `(df["salary"] == ">50K")` que pandas interpretaría como un selector de columnas. Eso también sería incorrecto. Y aún si hubiera funcionado y hubiera seleccionado algo, el resultado habría sido un dataframe al que luego aplicas `.count()`, que ya vimos que no es adecuado porque produce un montón de contadores (uno por columna). El array de contadores que hubieras obtenido, lo estabas dividiendo por `higher_education`, lo que te daría un array de números como resultado, y todo eso estaba entre corchetes en una expresión que se resumiría así:

```
df[array de numeros resultantes] * 100
```

De nuevo eso no tiene sentido porque se intentaría usar ese array de números para seleccionar elementos dentro de `df`, pero el array no tiene el formato apropiado (ni significaría nada esa operación). Y luego multiplicas por 100 lo que hubiera salido (que sería en todo caso una selección dentro de `df`).

Es decir, muchas cosas sin sentido. La solución era mucho más simple.

En realidad no quieres seleccionar elementos dentro de `df`, pues eso ya lo hicimos antes. Lo que queremos es seleccionar dentro del dataframe `higher_education` que obtuvimos antes (en mi versión sin el `.count()`), con una expresión de este estilo:

```
higher_education[higher_education.salary == ">50K"]
```

Eso selecciona dentro del dataframe `higher_education` (que ya tenía solo las filas de los bachelor, master y doctorate) aquellos con salario elevado. El resultado de esto es otro dataframe que tiene solo ya los de educación superior y además ricos. Aplicando `len()` sobre éste contamos cuántos son. Dividiendo por `num_num_higher_education` ya tienes el porcentaje buscado:

```
higher_education_rich = len(higher_education[higher_education.salary == ">50K"]) / num_higher_education * 100
```

Sale en este caso `46.535843011613935`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que los filtros los hagas siempre por pasos para que no sea confuso ni para ti ni para los lectores. Por lo que entendí tienes que filtrar :

1. Por personas que tienen un nivel académico
2. Por personas que ganan más de 50 K.

Yo implementaría el siguiente código.

Primero me quedaría con los conteos que realizaste:

```
higher_education = df[df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")].count()
lower_education = df[~df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")].count()
```

Luego aplicaría los filtros que necesitas de la siguiente manera:

```
filter = (df["education"].str.contains("Bachelors|Masters|Doctorate")) & (df["salary"] >= "50000"))
df_filter = df[filter]
df.head(5)
```

Finalmente sacaría tus porcentajes:

```
higher_education_rich = df_filter.count() / higher_education * 100

lower_education_rich = df_filter.count() / lower_education * 100
```

Por favor indícame si corriendo el código resuelve lo que necesitabas, en caso contrario, pásanos un extracto de tu base para poder recrear correctamente los df y entender mejor tu caso.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola Ricardo, el codigo de abulafia resuelve mi problema, asi como tambien el tuyo (aunque de una manera diferente). Gracias!

Comment: No hay de que Mati, a la orden.